# How to add a member to an existing PowerShell object?

Tags: powershell, wmi, windows-server-2012, powershell-5.0, get-wmiobject

The following powershell gets an object of Computer System information:

```
> $o = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName .
> $o

# output

# Domain              : somedomain.com
# Manufacturer        : VMware, Inc.
# Model               : VMware Virtual Platform
# Name                : MYSERVER
# PrimaryOwnerName    : Windows User
# TotalPhysicalMemory : 17179332608
```

I add a new member `TotalPhysicalMemoryGB` to the object `$o`, as follows:

```
> $o = Add-Member -Input $o @{TotalPhysicalMemoryGB=([math]::round($t.TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB))} -PassThru
```

This appears to work as I can access the member:

```
> $o.TotalPhysicalMemoryGB

# output
# 16
```

However, when I print the whole object again, the member `TotalPhysicalMemoryGB` does not appear in the member list:

```
> $o

# output

# Domain              : somedomain.com
# Manufacturer        : VMware, Inc.
# Model               : VMware Virtual Platform
# Name                : MYSERVER
# PrimaryOwnerName    : Windows User
# TotalPhysicalMemory : 17179332608
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the new member included when I print `$o`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *don't print the whole object* by just output it to the console. There is a *predefined view* that specifies which properties of a `System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_ComputerSystem` is printed.

You can get a full list of all properties by using the `Format-List` cmdlet:

```
$o | Format-List *
```

Now you will find your previously added property.

As a workaround, you could also manually select the properties you want to output by using the `Select-Object` cmdlet:

```
$o | Select-Object Domain, Manufacturer, Model, Name, PrimaryOwnerName, TotalPhysicalMemory, TotalPhysicalMemoryGB
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to Select-Object with the predefined view and just specify the additional properties? i.e. rather than having to hard-code the default values.